# how to upload the .sql file onto big query using bq command line

Tags: google-bigquery

when using bq command tool, can I directly upload the `.sql` file.
because it shows that the specified file is missing when executing the code [to find the command](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-sql-dml)

I have tried this one approach:

`while read -r q; do
    bq query --project_id=my-proj --dataset_id=sample_db --nouse_legacy_sql "$q"
done < <(grep '^INSERT' sample_db_export.sql)`

These PowerShell commands also read lines beginning with INSERT and run the queries using the bq command-line tool.

`Select-String -pattern '^INSERT' ./sample_db_export.sql |
    %{ bq query --project=my-proj --dataset_id=sample_db --nouse_legacy_sql $_.Line }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you are asking. If you have the query in a file called `sample_db_export.sql`, just pipe it as input to `bq query`. For example,

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false < sample_db_export.sql
```

Comment: i just want to upload a .sql file onto big-query using bq-command line tool. so i search for the command.